# TypeScript: access static method of a class

Tags: static, typescript

Still new at TypeScript so this question may sound dumb to some of you. I have a ToolTip class like this:

```
class ToolTip{
    public static show (str:string):void{
        console.log ("ToolTip show():" + str);
    }
    public static hide():void{
        console.log ("ToolTip hide()");
    }
}
export = ToolTip;
```

And I want to call it from another class

```
import ToolTip = require ("app/view/common/Tooltip");

class Button  {
......
    private handleMouseEvent(event:MouseEvent):void {
        switch (event.type) {
            case "mouseover":
                ToolTip.show("tool tip string");
                break;
            case "mouseout":
                ToolTip.hide();
                break;            
        }
    }
......
}

export = MenuItem;
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object app/view/common/Tooltip has no method 'show'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This works for me. Are you using 0.9.1.1?

Comment: I am using 0.9.1.1 too, using Webstorm EAP to compile it

Comment: I don't think Webstorm automatically picks up the latest TypeScript compiler. Can you reproduce the problem using `tsc.exe` ?

Comment: but this is a run time error, not at compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see the code works fine (compiles *and* runs) :

[image]

So possible reasons why it would not work for you :

- You did not compile with the `--module commonjs` option ([Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1))
- You have a folder named TootTip at the same level as `Tooltip.ts` which can cause nodejs to run what you might not have expected.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have found the error. When I change the file name from "Tooltip" to "ToolTip", the javascript never get updated, so it looks for Tooltip.js instead of ToolTip.js.